# Window Leaked in Async task while showing progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, window, progressdialog

I have one AsyncTask I am showing progress dialog in preExecute() method of an async task and dismissing it in postExecute() method of an async task.

I am also checking if the dialog is null or not. Also set setCancelable as false to progress dialog. Tried every solution given on SO but still window is getting leaked.

Async Task :

```
 public class RegisterUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    String api;
    JSONObject jsonParams;
    String muserName;
    String mfullName;
    String mpassword;
    String mmobileNo;
    String memailId;
    String mdeviceId;
    File mprofileImage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "Success";
    private Context mContext;

    public RegisterUserAsyncTask(Context context, String fullName, String userName, String password, String mobileNo, String emailId, String deviceId, File profileImage) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.muserName = userName;
        this.mpassword = password;
        this.mfullName = fullName;
        this.mmobileNo = mobileNo;
        this.memailId = emailId;
        this.mdeviceId = deviceId;
        this.mprofileImage = profileImage;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        if(progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

                   //Url
            api = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getregister();
            //Build JsonObject
            jsonParams = new JSONObject();
            String userName = this.muserName;  // params[0] is username
            String fullName = this.mfullName;  // params[1] is fullname
            String password = this.mpassword;  // params[2] is password
            String mobileNo = this.mmobileNo;  // params[3] is mobile
            String emailId = this.memailId;    // params[4] is emailid
            String deviceId = this.mdeviceId;  // params[5] is deviceid

            jsonParams.put("full_name", fullName);
            jsonParams.put("user_name", userName);
            jsonParams.put("password", password);
            jsonParams.put("mobile_no", mobileNo);
            jsonParams.put("email_id", emailId);
            jsonParams.put("device_id", deviceId);

            try {
                if(convertFileToString(this.mprofileImage)!=null) {
                    jsonParams.put("profile_image", convertFileToString(this.mprofileImage));

                    System.out.println("convertFileToString(profile_image)" + convertFileToString(this.mprofileImage));
                }
                else
                { jsonParams.put("profile_image", " null");}

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("convertFileToString(profile_image)");

            }

            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest(api, jsonParams);
            return request.sendRequest();

        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
        }
    }  //end of doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);


        if (response.has("message")) {
            String message = null;
            try {
                if (response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Could not Register ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RegisterActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

In activity calling RegisterAsyncTask in onClicked method of a button in onCreate() method of an activity.

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (checkValidation()) {

                    registerUser();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Form contains error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }



 private void registerUser() {
    String userName = edtuserName.getText().toString();
    String fullName = edtfullName.getText().toString();
    String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirm = edtconfirmPassword.getText().toString();
    String mobileNo = edtmobile.getText().toString();
    String emailId = edtemail.getText().toString();
    String deviceId = "233";

    new RegisterUserAsyncTask(RegisterActivity.this, fullName, userName, password, mobileNo, emailId, deviceId,mProfileImage).execute();

}
```

What to do for this?

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: `progressDialog.dismiss();` outside from `ifelse` condition with null check on `posstExecute`

Comment: i had tried that way too. Still was getting window leaked. @Dipalishah

Answer (score 3):

This problem may occurs due to "context". Progress dialog have a context of an activity but you may doing finish activity before complete the async task. So please check it once.

Comment: I am not finishing activity anywhere. I am calling RegisterAsyncTask in onCreate of an activity and in RegisterAsyncTask onPostExcecute if result is success then only I am finishing the registerActivity and calling new activity.@Kailas Bhakade